# Create horizontal scroll that has containers inside and paint them with a background color

Tags: html, css

I need to create a horizontal box with overflow-x
The thing that I need to do is something like:

```css
.table {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.table .row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row .data-column {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    line-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-xsm {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.body .row:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
   <div class="heading">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Id</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Active</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Balance</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Age</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Eye Color</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Name</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Gender</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="filter-row">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-id"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-isActive"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" class="visibility-hidden"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-age"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-eyeColor"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-name"></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-gender"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="body">
      <div class="cursor-pointer row" role="button" tabindex="0">
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>5eb99b22580edaed08109c1a</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span></span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>$2,928.72</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>40</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>blue</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>Glass Day</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>male</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cursor-pointer row" role="button" tabindex="0">
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>5eb99b2230bbbe9d0b2d0e7a</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span></span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>$2,358.71</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>25</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>blue</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>Monique Doyle</span></div>
         <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>female</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the background color doesn't fill the whole row, it just fills 'till the overflow starts.
I have tried using a Flexbox, but I only got posts using flex as container and elements inside, I mean I if choose that way, I'll have to set 1 scroll per each table row.

Comment: `display: inline-block;` to .body?

Comment: That doesn't work, it makes the rows smaller

Comment: are you sure? https://jsfiddle.net/kpr19d3h/

Comment: Yes, it works in that way, I have to use % in .col-xsm width, now it's set to PX, using % it doesn't work
Let me update the post using %

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns is known, you can consider the below configuration using `inline-flex;`. You can have the number of column as CSS variables to easily adjust it:

```css
.table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table .row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: calc(25% * var(--c)); /* each column 25% */
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row .data-column {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  line-height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-xsm {
  flex: 1; /* all the column equal*/
  min-width: 0; /* allow the to shrink so they stay equal */
}

.body .row:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 input {
   max-width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table" style="--c:7">
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Id</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Active</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Balance</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Age</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Eye Color</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Name</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><span>Gender</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-id"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-isActive"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" class="visibility-hidden"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-age"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-eyeColor"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-name"></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column"><input type="text" name="filter-gender"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="cursor-pointer row" role="button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>5eb99b22580edaed08109c1a</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span></span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>$2,928.72</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>40</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>blue</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>Glass Day</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>male</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cursor-pointer row" role="button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>5eb99b2230bbbe9d0b2d0e7a</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span></span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>$2,358.71</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>25</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>blue</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>Monique Doyle</span></div>
      <div class="col-xsm data-column false"><span>female</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Number of columns is unknown
it can be dynamic